# Reducing amount of code to add images

Tags: java

Trying to add 26 images to a game i am making. Right now i have 26 lines that im trying to shorten. this is what i have done so far.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    ImageIcon breifCase + i = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("img/case" + i + ".png")));
}
```

all i want to do is increase the end number on the variable name each name and also increase the number at the end of the image name.
its says i cannot converted to int. Cant think of how else i can go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of declaring the variables individually

```
// Don't do it like that!
ImageIcon breifCase0;
ImageIcon breifCase1;
ImageIcon breifCase2;
...
ImageIcon breifCase26;
```

make an array or a collection. Declare your array like this

```
ImageIcon[] breifCase = new ImageIcon[27];
```

Now you can slightly change your loop - and you are done!

```
for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    breifCase[i] = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("img/case" + i + ".png")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible in java (as far as I know) I suggest you using HashMap (or a List) for storing that.

```
List<ImageIcon> breifCase = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();

for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    breifCase.add(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("img/case" + i + ".png"))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not create dynamically named variables such as

```
ImageIcon breifCase + i
```

try using an array such as

```
ImageIcon breifCase [] = new ImageIcon [26];
```